# what the north, up, front usually represent in the world coordinate?

Tags: opengl, graphics, cad, solidworks

For the world coordinate, I read different representations like up vector, north vector, and front vector, I am wondering usually how is those map to XYZ?

Answer (score 1):

your choice,

though most have either:

- positive X due East, positive Y due North and positive Z up (called Z-up)
- positive X due North, positive Y up and positive Z due East (called Y-up)

both of these are right handed but that is not a requirement